# Searching phone number object in Elasticsearch with C#

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have an elasticsearch index that contains a phone number object with a contact document. The JSON is saved like this:

```
"contactId": "fd71b8e0-c3dd-4861-a45d-6917fdb48038",
"phone": { "country": "123",
           "area": "202",
           "number": "4567"
          },
"type": "business"
```

The mapping that is used in this document for the phone object is in the form:

```
,
      "phone": {
        "properties": {
          "area": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "country": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "number": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      },
```

We're querying the index using a C# application that's implementing Nest. In the application we construct a `Nest SearchDescriptor` object that is used as part of the client call. How can I add to the `SearchDescriptor` to search for a phone number when the user is searching for a string like 1232024567?

Comment: have you consulted with the online documentation located here
[Elasticsearch.Net and NEST](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/5.x/index.html)

Comment: Yes, I reviewed the documentation about was still unclear on how to implement the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way in which you could solve this is by also *indexing* but not *storing* the complete number i.e. index it to make it available to search on, but don't store it because it can be reconstituted from the `area`, `country` and `number` that you do store (and also probably index).

if `country`, `area` and `number` can always be determined from a complete phone number at index time e.g. always in a known format adhering to a pattern, then you might approach this differently by indexing and storing the complete phone number, and if `country`, `area` and `number` are only needed for search, then specifying the complete phone number as a [`multi-field`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/multi-fields.html), using a custom analyzer at index time on a field for each of `country`, `area` and `number` to extract the correct terms for indexing. at search time, you can then use these fields within the multi-field to find matches on `country`, `area` and `number` values.

Comment: Just reading your reply now!
What I went with was creating a new field that concatenated the 3 fields together (while removing some of the special characters) and used that as the field that is actually being searched. That was the user can type in a string that contains characters across multiple sub fields.
I think this is a little different from what you're suggestion, I'll look into how multi-field works.