# Searching across multiple address fields in Elasticsearch

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have an address saved in an elasticsearch document in the form of:

```
       "address": {
          "streetAddress": "123 Fake street",
          "city": "San Francisco",
          "region": "California",
          "postalCode": "94111",
          "country": "United States"
       },
```

How can I search the index using an input string that may contain data for each of the different fields. For example the user may search for "123 Fake street, San Francisco" - with or without the comma.

Would it make sense to tokenize the search string and then search for each word against each of the fields in questions? Or somehow concatenate all of the 5 fields into a separate address field and search on that? Currently we're using ngrams of size 2 - 12.

I had a question I asked here about phone numbers where I concatenated all of the phone number elements into one new field:
[Searching phone number object in Elasticsearch with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45925599/searching-phone-number-object-in-elasticsearch-with-c-sharp)

But the address situation is somewhat different in how uses may search for the documents.

Comment: Have you looked at the _all field?? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html

Comment: Thanks David. I haven't looked at this field yet, let me check it out...

Comment: Please be aware that the `_all` field is being disabled in Elasticsearch 6.0 by default and you will not be able to create an `_all` field in 6.0 indexes. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/breaking_60_mappings_changes.htm for more details.

Comment: We're currently in the process of upgrading to ES 5.1 so perhaps the _all field isn't the best option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan on sticking with Elastic 5 for a while, the [`_all` field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html) should satisfy your requirements.

As @Paige Cook pointed out in the comments above, the `_all` field will be [disabled by default](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/breaking_60_mappings_changes.html#_the_literal__all_literal_meta_field_is_now_disabled_by_default) in Elastic 6, with no way of enabling it on newly created indices in that version. It will, however, stay enabled on indices created in version 5.

If you read the section about the `_all` field in the breaking changes documentation listed above, you'll see references to the [`query_string`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) and [`simple_query_string`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-simple-query-string-query.html) methods (Both available through the NEST library as well as part of the HTTP API elastic provides) both of which will continue searching across all fields, even though the `_all` field is now disabled.

Hopefully one of these can solve the issue you are facing.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to move ahead with _all and refactor when the time comes when we move to ES 6.